# ¿Como puedo dar un salto de linea al escribir un archivo en Android?

Tags: java, android

he estado teniendo problemas con la escritura de archivos en Android, necesito llenar un formulario y después almacenarlo en un archivo PDF o txt, por el momento lo estoy intentando en txt pero no logro escribir más de un renglón en él, debido a que al tratar de escribir en él y poner saltos de línea al final de cada uno el contenido que está después del salto de línea no aparece.

Este es mi codigo de escritura:

```
    public void escribirDatos(){
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter fout = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(textEdit.getText().toString(), Context.MODE_APPEND));

        fout.write("Fecha: 29/8/2017 Hora: 22:00" + '\n' + "Lugar y área: \t\t Levantamiento realizado por:");
        fout.close();
        Log.e("Creación","Archivo creado correctamente");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Lectura:

```
public void leerDatos(){
    try {

        BufferedReader finLinea = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(textEdit.getText().toString())));
        String texto = finLinea.readLine();
        textView.setText(texto);
        finLinea.close();
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Ficheros","Error al leer archivo");

    }

}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: Agrega `fout.append('\n')` ó  `fout.append("\r\n")` ya sea por separado o dentro de la concatenación `+`

Comment: Se puede hacer el salto de linea en un ListBox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Revisa el siguiente [Link](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/03/java-write-to-a-file-code-example/) que es la documentacion del OutputStreamWriter

pero basicamente puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
public static void writeFile1() throws IOException {
File fout = new File("out.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bw.write("something");
    bw.newLine();
}


    bw.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente a tu `OutputStreamWriter` agrega un retorno de carriage y nueva linea:

```
osw.append("\r\n");
```

sería:

```
  try {
        OutputStreamWriter fout = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(textEdit.getText().toString(), Context.MODE_APPEND));

        fout.append("\r\n");  //Esto agregaría el salto de línea.

        fout.write("Fecha: 29/8/2017 Hora: 22:00" + '\n' + "Lugar y área: \t\t Levantamiento realizado por:");
        fout.close();
        Log.e("Creación","Archivo creado correctamente");

    }
```

---

Otra opción es usando el método `newLine()` de la clase [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)

> [newLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html): Se proporciona un método newLine (), que utiliza la propia
>   noción de separador de líneas de la plataforma, definida por la propiedad del sistema
>   **line.separator**. No todas las plataformas
>   utilizan el carácter de nueva línea ('\n') para finalizar líneas.
>   Llamar a este método para terminar cada línea de salida es preferible
>   a escribir un carácter de nueva línea directamente.

ejemplo:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout); 
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

   bw.write("Fecha: 29/8/2017 Hora: 22:00" + '\n' + "Lugar y área: \t\t Levantamiento realizado por:"); 
   bw.newLine(); //Escribe nueva linea.
```

Comment: Hay un método para eso, así no tenes que harcodear el salto de linea, de hecho existe porque los saltos de linea no son iguales en todos los lenguajes: "bw.newLine();"

Comment: hay un método pero no pertenece a OutputStreamWriter pertenece a BufferedWriter es otra opción la cual agregaré a mi respuesta.  A que te refieres a que los saltos de linea no son iguales? el OP pone un archivo de texto como ejemplo.